# Highchart amended waterfall chart

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I'm trying to create a (non-traditional) waterfall chart within an R markdown and am having a bit of difficulty getting the style I want.

Here is the code currently:

```
library(highcharter)


df = data.frame(Name = c("Start level","B","C","D", "E", "F", "G", "H","End level"),
                Value = c(900,-10,10,-10,10, -10, 10, -20, 880),
                Type = c("Start", "Reduction", "Rise", "Reduction", "Rise", "Reduction", "Rise", "Reduction", "End"))


hchart(df, type = "waterfall", hcaes(x=Name, y = Value, group="Type"), color = c("blue", "red", "black", "yellow"))
```

What I am aiming to have is the 'Start level' column on the far left, the 'End level' on the far right, with the components that drive the change between the two charts color-coded (as 'Rise' or 'Reduction' in the legend), with the waterfall section of the bars in line with the top of the 'Start level'. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You have the plot grouped by `Type`, so that means the waterfall effect only exists within each of these groups and makes a separate waterfall for each of these groups.

I'm going to guess that you want the waterfall to be across all aspects of the plot. That means that `group` needs to go. Since color is no longer assigned by a group, that will need to change.

When assigning colors by point, you need `colorByPoint` as well. To make this work, `color` and `colorByPoint` are best served within `hc_plotOptions`.

Additionally, you need to define that the last value is the `isSum` so that it doesn't add that value to the chart.

To get the order as you defined in `df$Name`, it can be defined in `hc_xAxis.

```
hchart(df, type = "waterfall", # removed group, color from hchart, added isSum
       hcaes(x = Name, y = Value, isSum = c(rep(F, nrow(df) - 1), T))) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = df$Name) %>%              # set bar order
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(colorByPoint = T,  # specify w/in series colors
                               colors = c("blue", rep(c("red", "black"), 3), 
                                          "red", "yellow")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what your are looking for but at least I am coming closer so this might help. A lot of issues seem to be coming from the grouping as each group gets "separated" from the other data points.

I tried:

```
library(highcharter)

df = data.frame(Name = c("Start level", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "End level"),
                Value = c(900, -10, 10, -10, 10, -10, 10, -20, 880),
                Type = c("Start", "Reduction", "Rise", "Reduction", "Rise", 
                         "Reduction", "Rise", "Reduction", "End"))
df$color <- ifelse(df$Type=="Start", "yellow", 
                   ifelse(df$Type=="Reduction", "red",
                          ifelse(df$Type=="Rise", "black", "blue")))

hchart(df, 
       type = "waterfall", 
       hcaes(x = Name, 
             y = Value, 
             color = color,
             isSum = c(rep(F,8),T)))
```

Resulting in:
[image]

So it is somewhat closer but there are two issues I was not able to solve yet:

1. The legend is gone, not sure how to add a custom legend in this case.
2. The colors are off, even though they are specified. I do not know why yet.

I will play around with it a bit more and edit this post if I find a solution. Just wanted to leave this here as a starting point. Other than that I am curious how to solve this (probably more elegant as well).